# How can I view AMQP traffic coming to/from my computer

Tags: amqp

I tried using Wireshark and filtering on "amqp" but nothing shows up. Does this confirm that no AMQP is coming in/out of my machine or is there some further setup that I need to do to see the AMQP traffic?

Comment: [Is the filter green](https://wiki.wireshark.org/AMQP)?

Comment: Yes, it's green. I may be looking for AMQPS data instead but I'm not sure. If it's AMQPS does that mean I have no way to see it?

Comment: AMQPS doesn't seem widely supported or standardized yet, looking at the search results; it's probably either SCTP or SSL. You can definitely see the traffic, and often parts of the protocol, but the contents will seem just 'random' bytes, as they are encrypted. I'd start by monitoring all traffic - no filter - examine some packets, and then filter them out if they are not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons Wireshark won't show decoded protocol packets:

1. Prerequisite protocol plugins aren't enabled
2. You're using a non-standard port

To check 1 above, you'll need to make sure that the enabled protocols (under Analyze->Enabled Protocols... in the UI menu) includes Ethernet, IPv4/6, and TCP.

As for 2 above, Wireshark won't attempt to identify all protocol on all ports, so protocol plugins specify the ports you can monitor on. For the AMQP plugin the only port you can monitor AMQP packets on is 5672. A lot of Wireshark plugins have a preferences page where you can define the ports to look for that protocol on but the AMQP plugin doesn't (at least it doesn't appear to in latest stable release 1.12.8, although [it looks like it has been implemented](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.network.wireshark.scm/42490), perhaps in the development release), so the only way to monitor AMQP traffic is to make sure you're using the default port of 5672.